# Trying to use regex matches between words using PHP

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I am trying to match HTML tags that might occur between words on a web page, using regex's.

For example, if the sentence that I want to match is "This is a word", I need to develop a pattern that will match something like "This is a `<b>word</b>`".

I've tried using the code below to prepare the regex pattern:

`$pattern = "/".str_replace(" ", .{0,100}, $sentence)."/si";`

This replaces all spaces by `.{0,100}` and uses the `s` modifier to match any character. However, I am getting undesired results with this.

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Is it important to keep the existing HTML (i.e. if you're trying to replace the matched string)? If not, you could strip the HTML tags and then run your match.

Comment: In order to match a pattern, there has to be some criteria to match on. How are you going to determine the pattern you want to match? What is the criteria? IE: Match the first 4 words...etc. Without that it is hard to help you come up with a pattern that works.

Comment: There is a lengthy background to how I'll come up with the pattern, but just to cut a long story short, let's assume we have a string "This is a word". I want to derive a regex from this that will match `"This is a <b>word</b>"`

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`ereg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) or [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function when you are trying to perform a regular expression search and replace.

Comment: ereg_replace is depreciated. Better to stick to preg_replace.

Comment: What the hell? No one told me ereg_replace had gone down in value! ;)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, Sell Sell Sell!

Answer (score 0):

I put this together very quickly, so it probably doesn't cover all edge cases, but I think it at least partially matches your requirements. Also, I haven't tried it in PHP.

```
/[^\s>]+[\s]*(<([^>]+)>)(.*)(</\2>)[\s]*[^\s<]+/g
```

In the following example:

```
<p>This is a <b><i>nice</i> sentence</b>.</p> <p>Here's another sentence.</p>
```

It only matches the first sentence, in the following groups:

1. `<b>`
2. `b`
3. `<i>nice</i> sentence`
4. `b`

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to achieve? Parsing an html document with regex *might* not be the best solution. You can use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for what you've described (so far).
E.g. finding all rows in a table that contain the text `this is a word`:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml('<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
  <table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>lalala</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>this is a <b>word</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>lalala</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td><b>And this is a</b> word, too</td></tr>
  </table>
</body></html>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($xpath->query('/html/body/table/tr[./td[contains(., "this is a word")]]') as $tr) {
  foreach($tr->childNodes as $td) {
    echo $td->nodeValue, ' ';
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

prints

```
2 this is a word 
4 And this is a word, too
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression

```
%(<[^>]+?>)\s*?((?:\w+\s*)*)\s*?(</[^>]+?>)%im
```

will grab basic words, including simple multiple word phrases that are between a proper opening and closing tag, and group the full match, the opening tag, the word/phrase and the closing tag so you can access each easily.

So lets say your input will be html source code. Then run preg_match_all with the PREG_SET_ORDER flag. This will return an array of matches arrays, useful for looping through with foreach().

In this function below, $html is your source page that you want to search, and $matches is an empty array passed by value that the function will fill in with your results for you.

```
<?php
$html='
This is a <b>word</b>.
This is not a word.
This is a <span>three word phrase</span>.
';

$regex ='%(<[^>]+?>)\s*?((?:\w+\s*)*)\s*?(</[^>]+?>)%im';

preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($matches as $val) {
    //$val[0] will always be the entire match with the tags
    echo "full match: " . $val[0] . "\n";

    //$val[1] will always be the opening tag
    echo "opening tag: " . $val[1] . "\n";

    //$val[2] will always be the word or words, if separated by spaces
    echo "word: " . $val[2] . "\n";

    //$val[3] will always be the closing tag
    echo "closing tag: " . $val[3] . "\n\n";
}
?>
```

The above script will output:

```
full match: <b>word</b>
opening tag: <b>
word: word
closing tag: </b>

full match: <span>three word phrase</span>
opening tag: <span>
word: three word phrase
closing tag: </span>
```

Comment: oh great, i just realized this question is two years old. I'm such a noob